# How to unit test entities with DatabaseGenerated fields?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

I've inherited an application where every entity has a `DateCreated` field with the `DatabaseGenerated` attribute using `DateTime.Now` on inserts. While beneficial, this introduces problems when unit testing.

I'm a believer in not depending on a volatile resource like a real database during unit testing so my preference would be to use an in-memory solution but neither localdb or Sqlite support the attribute without code changes. [EF Core in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/entity-framework-core-in-action?query=efcoreinaction) seems to confirm that it's not possible with in-memory databases in general.

But even if I'm willing to look past an in-memory database, the business needs require a diverse set of created dates to be tested and if I want to start fresh every test cycle (and I do) I can only generate data for `DateTime.Now`.

While I can write some code to operate on real db data that is dumped to application memory where I alter the created date as needed, that's another thing to maintain and support.

Is there another way I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't come with the better solution to mock DateTime. But this satisfied my needs:

```
var triggerTimeStamp = user.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(User.DateCreated));  
triggerTimeStamp.SetValue(user, DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromHours(17));
```

I add this to my unit tests where I need to check some specific date time related logic.